# How to POST data to this website using curl?

Tags: php, function, curl

I'm working on a project to send sms using HTTP API of clicksend SMS. I'm trying to post data using curl function but I'm having difficulties.

These are post fields:

> Method,Username,Key,to,message,sender

I want it to be done using curl function with my HTML form.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['number'])) {
 $pass = $_POST['password'];
 $num = $_POST['number'];
 $msg = $_POST['msg'];
 $sender = $_POST['sender'];

  // Passwords Start Here.....!!
 if ($pass == "jony") {
 echo "Correct Password....!!"; 
}
 else {
 echo "Wrong Password....!! ";
exit;
}
// Passwords End Here....!!
echo "Success   "  . $num . "  ";


 $LOGINURL = "https://api.clicksend.com/http/v2/send.php?method=http&username=username&key=KEY";
$POSTFIELDS = '&to=' . $num .'&message=' . $msg . '&senderid=' . $sender;
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer); 
   curl_exec ($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Make $ POSTFIELDS an array and CURL will querystring it for you

Comment: i've done check the code above!

Comment: $params = array(
'method'    => 'http',
'username'  => $user,
'key'       => $apikey,
'to'        => &to,
'message'   => $msg,
'senderid'  => $sender
);
$request =  $url.'/http/v2/send.php';
$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
print_r($response);

Comment: You wrote 'having difficulties', but that's way to vague for anyone to help you. Are you saying that the SMS is not being sent as a result of running the script and you are unsure why?

Comment: Make sure you `curl_close($ch);` at the end.

Comment: i can send whole script which i made you can check it out

Comment: Check your CURL errors then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have blanked out the actual username and key in the login URL, right? If not, you will need to use those provided by ClickSend. No doubt you'll be able to set up the API key in the account somewhere etc...

Also I see that `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is set to `1`, but since you are debugging at the moment you should either set it to `0` (which will show you the 'response' from ClickSend after running the script)

The rest looks fine. Once you get the ClickSend response rendering to the page it should give you a better idea of what the root of the problem is.

Try running this script, tell us what the page says.

```
<?php
  //You *MUST* define your username and key. It is availible in your ClickSend dashboard.
  $_my_clicksend_username = "clicksendusername";
  $_my_clicksend_key = "abc123";
  //You *MUST* define the 'to', 'message' and 'senderid'
  $to        = "the recipient";
  $message   = "the message";
  $senderid  = "the sender ID";
  //Tell CURL where to post, and what data to send.
  $url = "https://api.clicksend.com/http/v2/send.php?method=http&username=$_my_clicksend_username&key=$_my_clicksend_key";
  $data = '&to=' . $to .'&message=' . $message . '&senderid=' . $senderid;
  //Now tell CURL to POST the data and write the outcome on the page. 
  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); 
  curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks it's working i was wrong at CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set to 1 when i changed this its working perfectly thanks for you answer!

Comment: I'm not sure how that itself solved your problem since it was just a debugging tactic, but I am glad that it helped you solve your problem. Please click the 'tick' next to my answer to mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: Basics still work, but full url has been changed...remember to urlencode any spaces

Answer (score -1):

You are almost right.

The only thing is you need follow only certain things, that's all, no need to checkout user agent there. And it seems like you are integrating SMS API.

So the format goes something like this.

```
// Send the POST request with cURL
$data = "user=username&&pass=pasword";
$ch = curl_init('http://yourdomainname.com/filename.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); //This is the result from Textlocal
curl_close($ch);
```

This could be more then enough I believe.

Comment: Walaikum salam, & thanks for answer but i tried this not working for me if you can do it for me that would be greag help

Comment: This answer is unhelpful. The poster has already posted an example of his current CURL script, but you have just posted an example of a generic CURL script. The only information you have provided that is useful is that his concerns are not with the user agent, and since you probably haven't checked the ClickSend API there is a small possibility that user agent *does* need to be defined. I would suggest *trying* to omit it to see if it helps.

Comment: sure why not. but before initializing anything. i need to know whether some error occuring or something like that!!

Comment: I understand, but you should tell the poster that his script example is not currently outputting, and that it should for us to be able to help him further. You should also mention that his `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` should be set to `true` in order for him to see that feedback.

Comment: 1owk3y , basically i'm new to stack that's why having difficulties!

Comment: can you join me on chat?

Comment: I'm afraid that undermines the purpose of Stack Overflow. If you have attempted my solution, please update your answer explaining what the screen says after you run the script.